# get same session object in jsp and Servlet Filter?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am setting an attribute to the session object in jsp page as shown below:

```
String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
session.setAttribute("remoteAddr",remoteAddr);
```

Then, I am trying to retrieve that session attribute in the servlet filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
String remoteIP = httpServletRequest.getSession(false).getAttribute("remoteAddr");
}
```

But I am getting a null value for the session object here. What is the correct way to get same session object here?

Comment: Are you sure `request.getRemoteAddr()` does not give you a null value in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The method [HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)) may return `null`

> If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method returns null.

A [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)  may be invoked before a resource is requested or after it is requested depending on when you perform `chain.doFilter(request, response);`

In your case it seem that you query the session before the jsp is executed, i.e. doing something like this:

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
String remoteIP = (String) httpServletRequest.getSession(false).getAttribute("remoteAddr");

// pass the request along the filter chain
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Changing it to

```
// pass the request along the filter chain
chain.doFilter(request, response);

HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
String remoteIP = (String) httpServletRequest.getSession(false).getAttribute("remoteAddr");
```

Will get it to work, but I doubt this is what you intend to do, since you probably want to check the remote IP and decide whether to allow access or deny it to the requested resource, in which case you may want to do something like this:

```
String remoteIP= request.getRemoteAddr();

if(remoteIP.matches("some pattern")) {
    ((HttpServletResponse)response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
} else {
    // pass the request along the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);  
}
```